# スタック・オーバーフローMetaがモバイル表示されている？

Tags: サポート, モバイル

スタック・オーバーフローMetaの画面表示がモバイル用の画面みたいになってます。
画像を添付するメニューがないので、画像を示す事が出来ませんが…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フッターの方で「完全なサイト」のリンクがあります。

それをクリックするとモバイルビューから切り替えができます。

問題があれば、ブラウザのコンソールにJavascriptを実行してください：

`StackExchange.switchMobile("off")`

リンクと同じ方法ですので、どっちでも、同じ結果があるはずです。

Comment: 「完全なサイト」をクリックしたら直りました。ありがとうございます。